# How to remove elements in HTML from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that appends elements into my HTML page. I want to add a function that when a user clicks a button in HTML it will remove the associated HTML content from the page.

```
$("#keywords").append("<td><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" /> " + id + "</td>");
```

The code above is how I am adding elements to the HTML. So in this case when a user clicks the appended image `<td><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" />`
 will be removed from the HTML.

This is what I have now that isn't working:

```
$(".delete_filter").click(
function(){
    ($(this).parent()).remove();
});
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping `$(this).parent()` in brackets? Try `$(this).parent().remove()` instead. Also, can you be more specific than 'isn't working'? What's happening that isn't what you expect? If nothing appears to be happening, are you getting any Javascript errors?

Comment: It works fine for me . http://jsfiddle.net/yf8jv/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I agree that that's a strange way to write it, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the element is being dynamically added `click()` will not work as it only sees elements which were available on load.

Try this instead:

```
$("#myTable").delegate(".delete_filter", "click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Or in jQuery 1.7+

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ".delete_filter", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

Comment: The relevant `td` will not be part of the DOM either since they get appended too.

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, you should accept some answers to your previous questions, here's how to do it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that you're adding the `click` handler before the DOM element is added to the page.  Hence it's not binding to that element.  Try using `on` instead

```
$('table').on('click', '.delete-filter', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

The `on` API is new to jQuery 1.7.  If you're using an earlier version then try `live`

```
$('table').delegate('.delete-filter', 'click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Your `.on()` solution is equivalent to the `$(".delete_filter").click(` code. To make `.on()` do event delegation, you need to place the handler on an ancestor, and give a selector, like: `$("#keywords").on('click','.delete_filter',func...`

Comment: If you're using a version prior to 1.7 you should use `delegate` rather than `live`. "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()." [.live() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @amnotiam interesting, didn't realize that.

Comment: Yeah, `on` is basically `bind` and `delegate` rolled into one, the two being distinguished by the presence of the selector argument. +1 on the update.

Answer (score 1):

The elements won't be part of the html at the point you set up your event listeners, try the following:

```
$('table').delegate('.delete_filter', 'click', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#keywords').on('click', '.delete_filter', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

Probably your code doesn't work because the delete_filter class objects aren't there yet when the code is executed. The on syntax binds it dynamic so it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#keywords").append("<td><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" /> "  + id + "</td>");

    $(".delete_filter").on("click", function(event) {

     // Not sure why you had this section wrapped in a function() tag, wasn't necessary
     $(this).parent().remove();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Bind the event *after* appending the item to DOM.

```
$("#keywords").append("<td><img src=\"images/delete.png\" class=\"delete_filter\" /> " + id + "</td>");
$(".delete_filter").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```